# JSON.parse - How to handle capitalized Boolean values?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonparser

I am working on a Node.js application that needs to handle JSON strings and work with the objects.

Mostly all is well and `JSON.parse(myString)` is all I need.

The application also gets data from third parties. One of which seems to be developed with Python. 
My application repeatable chokes on boolean values since they come captialized.

Example:

```
var jsonStr = "{'external_id': 123, 'description': 'Run #2944', 'test_ok': False}";

try{
   var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
}catch(err){
   console.err('Whoops! Could not parse, error: ' + err.message);
}
```

Notice the `test_ok` parameter - it all is good when it follows the Javascript way of having a lower case `false` boolean instead. But the capitalized boolean does not work out.

Of course I could try and replace capitalized boolean values via a string replace, but I am afraid to alter things that should not get altered.

Is there an alternative to `JSON.parse` that is a little more forgiving?

Comment: not a valid JSON string

Comment: JSON does not have capitalised Booleans. Whatever creates that string is plain broken. Like, totally broken, you're missing double quotes on the strings too. The API is literally just sending `str(the_object)`

Comment: Did you just copy this from a python dictionary?

Comment: If you got this from a Python dict, use `json.dumps` to convert it into a valid JSON string.

Comment: In addition to the capitalized "False", the property names are quoted with single quotes instead of double quotes. That's simply not JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I don't mean to be rude but according to [json.org](https://json.org/), its an invalid json. That means you'll have to run a hack where you have to identify stringified boolean "True" and convert it to "true" without affecting a string that lets say is "True dat!"

Comment: It's not being rude to say that the string is not valid JSON but, if possible, the issue should be fixed in the API response.

Comment: That and all the single quotes surrounding keys and values will lead to a parsing error. So you'd also have to replace them. But not if you have the string `'True, it\'s awesome!'`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would not recommend using the code below.  This is just to demonstrate how to convert **your** input string into a valid JSON.  There were problems, one is the Boolean **False**, and another is the single quotes around property names.  I'm not positive but I believe those need to be double quotes.

I don't believe having to convert a string into a valid JSON is a good choice.  If you have no alternative, meaning you don't have access to the code generating this string, then the code below is still not a good choice because it will have issues if you have embedded quotes in the string values. i.e. you would need different string replace logic.

Keep all this in mind before using the code.

```js
var jsonStr = "{'external_id': 123, 'description': 'Run #2944', 'test_ok': False}";

try {

    jsonStr = jsonStr.replace(/:[ ]*False/,':false' ).replace( /'/g,'"');
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
    console.log( jsonObj );
} catch (err) {
    console.err('Whoops! Could not parse, error: ' + err.message);
}
```

Comment: Breaks on `"{'isCat': False, 'isDog': False}"`. I only bring this up because scrubbing the data post-hoc is generally prone to small errors that add up. Better to just fix where the data is coming from to begin with than fix it on the fly.

Comment: i do believe that is what I implied above.  What the 1st thing I stated?   Anyway, thanks for comment